# What the format and contentType should be?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm creating an Asp.net core web api to accept the multiple part http post. Here is the raw http post, There are three text strings and one uploaded binary file (can be any type of file).

```
POST http://localhost:5001/api/ClosingDoc HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 6957
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8082
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDTtxFp41DIpArUZ0
Referer: http://localhost:8082/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4

------WebKitFormBoundaryDTtxFp41DIpArUZ0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Id"

ANYTHING001
------WebKitFormBoundaryDTtxFp41DIpArUZ0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="docType"

Test
------WebKitFormBoundaryDTtxFp41DIpArUZ0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="comments"

Test
------WebKitFormBoundaryDTtxFp41DIpArUZ0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="control.PNG"; filename="control.PNG"
Content-Type: image/png

 PNG
.....
```

I created the class `ClosingDocInputFormatter : InputFormatter`, now I need to added it the following code in **Startup.cs**.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<Models.StaticDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    services.AddMvc(o => {
        o.InputFormatters.Add(new ClosingDocInputFormatter());
        //??? x.OutputFormatters.Add(new ClosingDocOutputFormatter()); // No need?
        o.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat(
            "???", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("????")) // What the strings should be?
    });
    services.AddCors();
}
```

Questions.

1. Do I need to define the OutputFormatter since I only need to do the post part?
2. The method `o.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat` need two string parameters. What the values they should be?

Comment: http://www.strathweb.com/2016/02/formatfilter-and-mediatypemappings-in-asp-net-core-1-0-mvc/

Comment: The link says it can be any arbitrary string. I added `closingDoc` and `application/closingDoc` respectively. However I still got the error of `System.InvalidOperationException: No media types found in 'MyService.Formatters.ClosingDocInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes'. Add at least one media type to the list of supported media types.`

Comment: I think you didn't use the `FormatFilter`. See the last section.

Comment: any arbitary string but should be a valid media type for that extension

Comment: I added `[FormatFilter]` for the controller and still got the error. I'm doing the post so the url is `http://localhost:5001/api/ClosingDoc `. Error: `System.InvalidOperationException: No media types found in 'MyService.Formatters.ClosingDocInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes'. Add at least one media type to the list of supported media types.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.InputFormatter.CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.<BindModelAsync>d__3.MoveNext()`

Comment: try adding a `[Route("[controller]/{id}.{format?}")]` to the action.

Comment: I got the error `angular.js:12011 POST http://localhost:5001/api/ClosingDoc 404 (Not Found)` after adding `[Route("[controller]/{id}.{format?}")]` or `[Route("api/[controller]/{id}.{format?}")]` to the `Post` action.