# System.InvalidOperationException: No media types found in '....Formatters.ClosingDocInputFormatter.SupportedMedi‌​aTypes'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I got the following error when the client posts `http://localhost:5001/api/ClosingDoc`, which posts a file and a few other form inputs in one submit. More information can be found in [What the format and contentType should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39862906/what-the-format-and-contenttype-should-be). Here is the controller.

```
[FormatFilter]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ClosingDocController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Post([FromBody]ClosingDocVM closingDoc)
    {
        nlogger.Info($"ClosingDoc of {closingDoc.Id} is uploaded."); //Never reach here
    }
```

In my `startup.cs`,

```
services.AddMvc(o => {
    o.InputFormatters.Add(new ClosingDocInputFormatter());
    o.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat(
        "ClosingDoc", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/ClosingDoc"));
});
services.AddCors();
```

`ClosingDocInputFormatter.cs`

```
public class ClosingDocInputFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var type = context.ModelType;
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        MediaTypeHeaderValue requestContentType = null;
        MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out requestContentType);

        var result = readStream(type, request.Body);
        return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(result);
    }

    private object readStream(Type type, Stream stream)
    {
        Type itemType;
        var typeIsArray = false;
        IList list;
        if (type.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0)
        {
            itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            list = (IList)(Activator.CreateInstance(type));
        }
        else
        {
            typeIsArray = true;
            itemType = type.GetElementType();

            var listType = typeof(List<>);
            var constructedListType = listType.MakeGenericType(itemType);

            list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(constructedListType);
        }


        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = new string[] { };
            {
                var itemTypeInGeneric = list.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GenericTypeArguments[0];
                var item = Activator.CreateInstance(itemTypeInGeneric);
                var properties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    properties[i].SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(values[i], properties[i].PropertyType), null);
                }

                list.Add(item);
            }

        }

        if (typeIsArray)
        {
            Array array = Array.CreateInstance(itemType, list.Count);

            for (int t = 0; t < list.Count; t++)
            {
                array.SetValue(list[t], t);
            }
            return array;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Do I missed anything?

Comment: Since you are deriving from InputFormatter you can find a field called "SupportedMediaTypes". Maybe you can try adding your "requestContentType" to that. At least that's what you find in many examples online if you google for input- or outputformatters. 
I have another problem though: I somehow can't add stuff to SupportedMediaTypes because I'm having import problems. But you could still try that...